# Multiple variables are not getting printed in same line in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Please see the below shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the date in (YYYY-MM-DD) format: "
read dt
i=00
echo "/opt/log-$dt_$i"
```

Expected Output :

```
Enter the date in (YYYY-MM-DD) format:
2020-06-18
/opt/log-2020-06-18_00
```

But Getting the below output:

```
Enter the date in (YYYY-MM-DD) format:
2020-06-18
/opt/log-00
```

Please suggest?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ would have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `echo` line to this:

```
echo "/opt/log-${dt}_${i}"
```

**Explanation:**

An `_` (underscore) is a valid character in a variable name, so bash is looking for `$dt_` and `$i`. Since `$dt_` is not defined, it doesn't print it. Bash provides the alternate variable syntax using `${}` to explicitly isolate the variables when performing string interpolation like this.

Comment: The 2nd example is actually bad: you are actually *unquoting* the `dt` variable, which exposes you to word splitting and globbing. Especially since we're directly dealing with user input that you can't trust.

Comment: Yes, good point. It was kind of an afterthought. I've removed it from my answer

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
echo "/opt/log-${dt}_$i"
#               ^  ^
#       curly brackets mandatory here
```

This is because you have to separate the variables with `_` that could be part of any variables.

Which editor do you use ? For me in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), it's clear:

[image]

Versus:

[image]

(the underscore become white)